# How can I "SIMD-fy" search queries to spatial hierarchical data structures such as k-d-trees, octrees, etc?

Tags: optimization, data-structures, simd

What strategies are there for efficient implementations of SIMD-accelerated search queries to CPU-based spatial data structures? For example, a ray query that returns a list of all intersected spheres in an octree that stores (references to) spheres. This consists of two major hurdles: SIMD-acceleration of the process of finding what objects in the tree need to be checked for intersection at all (e.g. in an octree, checking against the Octree's node AABBs) and then SIMD-based implementation of the actual intersection tests with the found objects. Given a list of objects to be tested for intersection, the latter problem seems easier to solve (it's a problem that doesn't have anything to do with the chosen data structure), but the former seems like a harder problem.

In an optimal case, I'd like to just (for example) check intersections with 4 (8, 16, etc...) rays at once against whatever is stored in the data structure.

This seems difficult for me since SIMD in this case by definition requires different elements of the query (e.g. every ray in a hypothetical 8-ray-set of queries) to execute the same code, but hierarchical data structures are all about using branches to quickly reduce the set of necessary tests. Is it even possible?

Alternatively, are there spatial data structures that are especially suited to this kind of parallelism?

Comment: You could almost certainly "SSE-fy" individual checks. For example a point has 4 components (if you make the 4th 1 to indicate point rather than vector), a plane has 4 components (there are 4 constants associated with the plane equation). You can dot these two values to get the distance from the plane for normalized plane equations and for non-normalized plane equations you get an inequality. The dot product can be "SSE-fyed." There should be other similar SSE optimizations on the per object level.

Comment: @Apriori Yes, I just noticed a mistake in my question. The actual problem I want to get to is how to SIMD-fy the process of finding which objects need to be checked for intersection, so for example checking intersection of the set of rays with the AABBs of an octree. I'd like to be able to do that with multiple rays at once.